# Xamarin Installation issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mono, monodevelop, xamarin

I'm trying to install Xamarin for Android and I'm having a some issue and I can't find any help anywhere. Even, I have tried to run installation as Administrator but same error keep appearing : 
This is the Log File `Error Part`:

```
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.396] [Info] Installing an MSI
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.400] [Info] Database path: <USER_HOME>\Temp\Xamarin\downloads\mono-android-4.6.02001.msi
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.404] [Info] Starting MSI installation: msiexec /i "<USER_HOME>\Temp\Xamarin\downloads\mono-android-4.6.02001.msi" /quiet /passive /log "<USER_HOME>\Temp\tmp76AB.tmp" ADDLOCAL=MonoDroidSDK,VisualStudioAddin,VisualStudio11Addin
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.608] [Info] MSI installation process exited with code 1620
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.611] [Info] Status: failed.
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.615] [Info] InstallMsi failed for '<USER_HOME>\Temp\Xamarin\downloads\mono-android-4.6.02001.msi'
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.618] [Exception] Exception was thrown.
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.618] [Exception] System.InvalidOperationException: MSI execution failed.
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.618] [Exception] à Xamarin.Web.Installer.WindowsInstallationArchiveHandler.InstallMsi(String file, Boolean needsPrivileges)
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.621] [Info] BEGIN >>>>>> msiexec log: '<USER_HOME>\Temp\tmp76AB.tmp'
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.626] [Info] END >>>>>> msiexec log: '<USER_HOME>\Temp\tmp76AB.tmp'
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.629] [Info] Status: failed.
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.632] [Exception] Installation of software item 'Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio' failed with exception.
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.632] [Exception] Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException: Installation of archive '<USER_HOME>\Temp\Xamarin\downloads\mono-android-4.6.02001.msi' failed with exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: MSI execution failed.
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.632] [Exception] à Xamarin.Web.Installer.WindowsInstallationArchiveHandler.InstallMsi(String file, Boolean needsPrivileges)
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.632] [Exception] à Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.InstallationArchiveHandler.Install(String path, Boolean needsPrivileges)
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.632] [Exception] --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.632] [Exception] à Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.InstallationArchiveHandler.Install(String path, Boolean needsPrivileges)
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.632] [Exception] à Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install(UInt32 tryNumber)
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.632] [Exception] à WindowsInstaller.ProgressPage.InstallationWorker()
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.635] [Info] Status: failed.
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.638] [Debug] Starting installation complete task.
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.641] [Info] Background installation worker completed.
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.644] [Info] Installation completed with failure
[2013-04-10 23:20:27.647] [Info] Status: failed.
```

Comment: You may have more luck at Xamarin: http://forums.xamarin.com/categories/android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [Chlebta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1310952/chlebta) said; try downloading the file directly.

I've updated the URL to the latest version:
http://download.xamarin.com/MonoforAndroid/Windows/mono-android-4.8.00013.msi

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem for the second time.

Here are the steps that allow me to solve it:

1. Uninstall all Xamarin product (Xamarin Android, Xamarin Studio etc)
2. Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions and delete Xamarin folder
3. Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions and delete Xamarin folder
4. Install Xamarin Studio or just mono-android-4.8.00013.msi as you need

I Hope it will help (and hope the problem will not occur again...)

Answer (score 1):

MSI was not complete: (7,627,523 bytes) vs (40,300,544 bytes) when downloaded direcly from URI http://download.xamarin.com/studio/Windows/XamarinStudio-5.0.0.878-0.msi